# Copying components across publication in Tridion 2009 SP1

Tags: 2009, broker, content-porter-2009

I am using SDL Tridion 2009. We use VBScript and JSP. I have a requirement to copy components across publications. How is this possible? Please suggest some ideas.

Answer (score 12):

You can use “Cross Copier” feature of Power Tool to copy items across publications. For more see the URL

http://sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/powertools.aspx

Below URL have some great thought by Bart which certainly be beneficial for you -

[How to move items from one publication to other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625700/how-to-move-items-from-one-publication-to-other)

Comment: I am planning to use http://sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/powertools.aspx as our QA's and content producers will be using this. So a Tool with easy UI is the preference. However, this tool does not open when installed, when i go in Cross Copier option and select 'Select item' option, the tree does not load and the message 'loading tree' keeps coming. Any help please.

Comment: Do below steps and let me know the update so that i can help you further 
1- Flush your browser cache.
2- Give permissions to network service on the powertools folder.

Comment: Ram,I did your mentioned steps, i tried to copy one component to a different publication... i can see that processing starts but i get the error, dont know the exact error but the last line is "If you are the system administrator please click here to find out more about this error." . When i click the link it takes me to the link http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8 . The link says that ASP is not installed, but i checked the server and ASP engine is allowed in iis.

Comment: The exact error is :
06/05/2013 11:55:11 found item Img gall test
06/05/2013 11:55:11 item type: 16
06/05/2013 11:55:11 processing Img gall test (tcm:129-14512)
06/05/2013 11:55:11 found node tcm:129-14512
06/05/2013 11:55:11 node now tcm:291-14512
06/05/2013 11:55:11 found node tcm:129-2338-2
06/05/2013 11:55:11 node now tcm:291-2338-2
06/05/2013 11:55:11 found node tcm:129-14511
06/05/2013 11:55:11 replacing from mapping
mapping updating xml: 
" xlink:title=""/></tcm:Data></tcm:Component> An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator.

Comment: Ram, can you give me your personal ID, so that we can chat. WE can then add your suggested solution for others to refer. My Id is varundoharey@gmail.com

Comment: Varun , chat is not possible as gmail is blocked in my office here. stackoverflow also have chat option. Have you achieved it through your score ?

Comment: By default the R5.3/2009 PowerTools only runs for administrators. Also, copying across publications requires the appropriate dependencies in the target publication. To be sure it's not a dependency, try copying down the BluePrint or in "sibling" publications.

Comment: Ram, I have not yet achieved that score, so chat is not possible :(.

Comment: Alvin... Before I try out that can You or Ram tell me how does choose mapping works? I can see radio buttons 'nasnl2nasuk', 'richoheurope2nasuk' and 3 fields each for  'Search for', 'Replace by '.. What are these fields , i keep these fields as blank and i get error 'replacing from mapping mapping updating xml:' after which i feel the code does not proceed.

Comment: Those seem to be example mapping files (see the xml in `\web\Powertools\etc\cc`), which, I believe, map identifiers between publications. I think the first option is the "empty" `.xml` file without a name (maybe try renaming it?). I actually don't remember getting cross copier working on R5.3--I'm not sure if I got stuck on the tree picker or in the actual copy. The code is all in the .asp if you want to replicate the behavior.

Comment: Alvin.... Yes the tree picker shows as blank.. and simply says loading tree, if we open in IE8, the page gives a loading error, so i use ie7 and i do not use the tree picker, i directly enter the tcms of the component and publication, but i am not sure why the seach for, replace by and the mapping field is there and what is the use of it.

Comment: Alvin, I guess you may be using Tridion 2011 on your machine, but if possible and if you do have environment for R 5.3, can you just try to copy a component to a different publication and let me know if it really works?

Comment: My requirement is to copy components across publication which have no relation and which means independent publications. Is this possible via powertools cross copier option?

Answer (score 8):

One nifty trick you can do is temporarily make your destination publication a child of the source by updating the Blueprint inheritance, such that all items in the source pub become inherited.  Then select the items inside your new temporary child pub, right-click, copy/paste.  The items copied will be local to your child pub.  After this, go back to your blueprint tree and un-inherit the publications to the way it was before.  This approach is assuming that your schemas are common to both publications.

Comment: I am planning to use http://sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/powertools.aspx as our QA's and content producers will be using this. So a Tool with easy UI is the preference. However, this tool does not open when installed, when i go in Cross Copier option and select 'Select item' option, the tree does not load and the message 'loading tree' keeps coming. Any help please.

Comment: One caveat: this (albeit nifty) trick only works when you want to copy an item down the blueprint chain, not up.

Comment: Right Quirijn. My requirement is to copy components across publication which have no relation and which means independent publications.

Comment: My requirement is to copy components across publication which have no relation and which means independent publications. Is this possible via powertools cross copier option?